# Append data without using cat command

Tags: linux, bash, unix

i was wondering weather is it possible to append data in a file without using `cat` command.
I've considered using sed to append data , but as of my knowledge sed only operates after loading the full data into the memory. please do correct me if i'm wrong on this.

Comment: Have you tried just simple I/O redirection with `>>` ? 
>> is used for appending data rather than > which will override.

Comment: Sed does not load the full data into memory.It is a "stream editor" - hence the name "sed".

Comment: I think you need to explain why you want to do this.

Comment: well this question just struck in my mind..& couldn't found any suitable answer, so basically  that's the only reason..

Comment: Do you want to *append* data; or *concatenate* data (which is the purpose of `cat`). Both tasks are slightly different...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append data to a file, you can simply use the [*append I/O-redirection `>>`*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). For instance:

```
echo "first line" > file
echo "next line" >> file
```

Or you could append an entire file

```
echo "$(<otherfile)" >> file
```

This command is however not advisable since it will load the entire file first into memory.

A better way is to use `tee`:

```
tee < otherfile >> file
```

Comment: but echo to display the content of a file, shouldn't you have to pass that content as an argument to echo ie. echo "$cat file" >>filename ??

Comment: `echo` does *NOT* read from stdin, so `echo < somefile >> file` won't work, it will only append an empty line to `file`.

Comment: @mata: That was indeed a mistake, don't know why that happened. Anyway now the answer provides a way to do this with `echo` although that's not advisable; and shows to use `tee` as well..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cat, you can also use echo command to do the same.

And ofcourse, `>>` operator does it.